# http://localhost/mydirector/ - echo mydirectory and avoid 404 error on localhost

Tags: php, apache

I have the URL http://localhost/mydirector/, I want to echo mydirectory and not have a 404 error.  mydirectory does not exist as a directory, but is taken as username. I am using Windows/apache/MySQL,PHP.  All this happening on localhost or 127.0.0.1

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Your question doesn't make real sense yet. Can you describe in detail what you want to achieve? What should happen when where?

Comment: @pekka
http://localhost is the domain name
mydirectory is the username

eg
http://digg.com/username

Comment: yes but what do you want to actually happen? What do you want to "echo" where? What is supposed to happen when somebody enters `/mydirectory`?

Comment: @Pekka I think you need a Kölsch. It could be a tough Monday. ;)

Comment: @zaf nice idea actually, I will ponder it over lunch :)

Answer (score 1):

if mod_rewrite isn't what you want, have you investigated mod_userdir?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite so that it internally rewrites the URL to another URL.

For example:

```
http://localhost/mydirector/
```

To:

```
http://localhost/index.php?z=mydirector
```

Then you can have index.php to read and echo the 'z' parameter value.

There is a lot of information on the net about using mod_rewrite to do this. For example: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting

Comment: Yup I can do that, and know that

Comment: @Jean what is your question then?

Comment: @pekka localhost is the domain name mydirectory is the username eg digg.com/username

Comment: @Jean yes but *what is your question?*

Comment: How do I get to do that on my local machine or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Jean get to do what? I still don't understand what your actual question is.

Comment: @Jean If my answer is what you were looking for but you don't know what the mod_rewrite code would be then accept this answer and open another question with this specific mod_rewrite problem. You'll get an answer from the mod_rewrite experts very fast.

Comment: @Jean Part of the confusion stems from the fact that you're contradicting yourself. In response to zaf's answer on mod_rewrite you say 'I can do that', then  you turn around and say 'How do I get to do that on my local machine?'. Try rephrasing using words you haven't used in a previous statement.